# Is parsing state from child component up in react a good practice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I am trying to change the state in the App components from a child components and I fell i would result to an issue later in my app

i tried passing the setFunction down to the child components then having it change the value in the app components

Comment: Share your relevant codes to check your errors and catch the problems.

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002). (A [mcve]).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be careful while doing it, but yes, you can do it.
Basically the issue you can encounter while doing this is: if the child AND the parent component try to update the state, thus leading to an infinite loop. (child updates the states which leads parent to re-render, and then updates the states, which leads the child to re-render etc...)

But if your parent component only "reads" from it, that's fine.

One another way to pass data to ANY component in your app would be to use React Contexts, but that's only if you need in many places. If that's just between one component and its child, the way you've done it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to use a library to state manage or React context. I highly recommend you eventrix it has a built-in event bus so you can communicate between components by events and manage global state. It's easy to implement and very fast.

Comment: thanks a lot, i'm learning react useContext and it looks cool and better